# Progress bar different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

how would you make progress bar in CSS that would have colours based on values etc. from 0% to 20% red colour, 20% to 40% blue... Also, I would want to show the colours all the time, not only when it hits the value(so that part of a progress bar would be red, part blue and the other colours from the beggining and that the colours would disappear as the value would go down).

Comment: Are you ok with using JS for this? Your question technically says "CSS" but it'd be a lot easier using JS/jQuery.

Comment: Yes, for sure. Thanks and sorry for my mistake. If possible I would prefer just JS but can deal with jQuery as well.

Comment: Are you trying to get a rainbow effect for the progress bar?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to achieve a gradient progress bar as per the current progress, then try `linear-gradient()` property in CSS.

Here is a working model:

```css
#prog-bar-cont {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 2.5em;
}
#prog-bar-cont #prog-bar {
  background: #ffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#prog-bar-cont #prog-bar #background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /*Actual Stuff*/
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, violet, #30b3fc, #70dc23, yellow, orange, #ff1076);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
}

#prog-bar-cont:hover #prog-bar #background {
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Rainbow Progress Bar</h1>
<p>Try hovering over the bar</p>
<div id='prog-bar-cont'>
  <div id="prog-bar">
    <div id="background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for, kindly accept the answer so that future users may find this post useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by nesting the progress bar in a parent element and applying the css property `overflow: hidden`.

You can change the `width` of the class `bar-clipper` to the desired percentage. i.e. `calc(300px * 0.6)` will show 60% of the bar.

```css
.bar-clipper {
    width: calc(300px * 0.8);
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar-wrapper span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bar-wrapper .bar1 {
    background-color: #163f5f;
}

.bar-wrapper .bar2 {
    background-color: #21639b;
}

.bar-wrapper .bar3 {
    background-color: #3caea3;
}

.bar-wrapper .bar4 {
    background-color: #f6d65b;
}

.bar-wrapper .bar5 {
    background-color: #ed543b;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar-clipper">
        <div class="bar-wrapper">
            <span class="bar1"></span>
            <span class="bar2"></span>
            <span class="bar3"></span>
            <span class="bar4"></span>
            <span class="bar5"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L13yrgbm/

Comment: Couldn't he just use a `linear-gradient()` to set *one* bar?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But the css for gradients with hard edges is not very pretty in my opinion.